# Is this question invalid, improperly worded, or asked in the wrong place?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive

I'm sure this question is asked a lot, but I'm still not satisfied with the answers I've read. The reason I ask this is, that I find these the answers to these questions extremely helpful. I also understand that it isn't an approved part of the Q&A format because there is no right or wrong answer. Is there somewhere else on this site that these questions can be asked, and if not, then why? I'm not so much trying to argue against it being closed, as I am asking where and how it is appropriate to ask.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967548/best-way-to-access-global-objects-like-database-or-log-from-classes-and-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question starts with

> Best way to ...

It was closed as not constructive because there is no **best** way. What is the definition of **best**? That is just subjective, and a discussion about it will not lead to a definitive answer.

The close note says it very well:

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, **but this question will likely solicit debate**, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: And the final *"Which do you believe is best and why? Feel free to propose additional solutions."* does not help the question along much either. And to address the OP's question; there really is no place in the network for questions like these.

Comment: Ok yes, I am aware of _why_ it was closed. I was more or less curious as to whether it would be suited anywhere else, because as I've said, there are times when these sort of open-ended/what-do-you-think-is-best? questions are incredibly helpful. I understand the logic behind closing it, I just think it is a shame that there appears to be no proper medium somewhere else for these types of questions.

Comment: In addition I think these questions are asked often, up-voted often, and answered often, which would lead me to believe that the community finds these helpful. As I've said I understand separating fact based questions from discussion/open-ended questions--I just don't understand why there appears to be no approved method on this network of facilitating that. For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site has over 1300 up-votes and yet is not considered a good question. How does that make sense?

Comment: @clementine: It does not fit a Q&A site of that profile. But that does not make it a bad question. It is a very good question actually. That is why people upvote it. But it is only there for historical reasons.

Comment: @juergen d: And I totally understand that. I'm not trying to argue that. The point I'm trying to make is, why hasn't anyone in SO said, "Let's make a place _where this is acceptable to ask_"? Because to me it appears it is both valuable and lacking, unless of course someone can point me in a different direction. I'm looking for some kind of a solution for what seems to be a pretty wide-spread, not well understood problem.

Comment: @clementine Maybe because a Q&A site is not suited for it, and that it should really be asked on a Forum. Asking these on the SE platform is like using a sledgehammer to put a screw into a wall.

Comment: @Diago I've I said before, I understand the logic that perhaps SE isn't the proper tool for that kind of question. My point is, is that I, and others it appears, are lacking a better tool. You say don't use a sledge hammer to put in a screw. I say, then give me a screw driver. I would gladly go to a forum, but I've yet to find a forum that has the community support and expertise that SE has. Do you know of a forum that would both meet the quality of answers and not discourage such questions?

Comment: @clementine If their isn't one. Start one. Simple. There is a reason such forums don't attract most experts.

Comment: @Diago I don't know. Maybe you're right. There has definitely been evidence of it being successful on SE though. Whether or not it could be successful on a large scale is up to debate. Do you really attribute SE's success to the fact that it discourages such questions? I feel certain there is much more to it than that. As far as starting one myself, I wouldn't know where to begin. Maybe I'll ask the community here for advice until my question is closed ;)

Comment: @clementine I most definitely do. Just because the questions get a lot of votes does not mean it is useful to the internet. There are other mediums. SE is not a silver bullet. Ask any user that has been around since the beginning. Users that leave because of it, never really added value in the first place.

Comment: @Diago Fair enough. Thank you for finally satisfying my curiosity and I'm sorry for pressing the issue through so many comments.